# Access Mustache object inside ICanHaz object

Tags: templates, mustache, icanhaz.js

I am using icanhaz inside my project. As per documentation it says that it includes the Mustache.js as well.

Now I want to access the embedded Mustache object's to_html() method as follows.

```
var message = Mustache.to_html(template, json, true);
```

I am  however getting error 'Mustache not defined'. Since Mustache is already included inside iCanHaz.js and I am successfully using  ICanHaz's other methods as well, I should not need to include entire Mustache library again just for calling this single method, Or should I?

I just want my template to render as normal string with values replaced from my json object. Any other simple and lightweight way is also appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to directly use the Mustache object.

Pass `true` to your normal ICanHaz render method to get the HTML string:

```
var message = ich.myTemplate(json, true);
```